# Wiring up Custom Model Binder to Custom AuthorizeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my MVC 4 web app, when I receives a request, I need to use a model from my custom binder to do some authorization logic. My problem is that I have no idea how to wire up my model and binder to the filter attribute. Is it possible?

**Edit**: add code block

```
public class FeatureCodeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    private string featureCode;
    private userPermissions;

    public FeatureCodeAttribute(string code, UserPermissions permissions)
    {
        featureCode = code;
        userPermissions = permissions;
    }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        if (HasFeature(userPermissions, featureCode))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

What I wanna do is to bind the UserPermissions object.

Answer (score 1):

**Model Binders comes into picture in mvc request pipeline after the authorization. So, basically mvc will first authorize the request in OnAuthorization method of AuthorizeAttribute and once the authorization is successful then MVC will try to bind the model.**

But still you can use the property in **OnAuthorization** method like this.

```
public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
{
    var value = filterContext.Controller.ValueProvider.GetValue("anyproperty");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But I don't understand what "anyproperty" should be placed ? Sorry for confusing. Please check my edited question again.

Comment: you wanted to bind model, in model you will have some property you can get those property value here using filter context and you can validate it here before actual modelbinding.